# Get spring application environment in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, environment, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Spring Boot application runs with 3 configurations:

- application.properties --> for development environment
- application-test.properties --> for test environment
- application-production.properties --> for production environment

How is it possible to get in thymeleaf environment the application is running?

I need to include the Google Analytics code only in production environment.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do the following if you only have one profile active at a time.

```
<div th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'production'}">
  This is the production profile - do whatever you want in here
</div>
```

The code above is based on the fact that the Thymeleaf's Spring dialect lets you access beans using the `@` symbol.  And of course the `Environment` object is always available as a Spring bean.

Also note that `Environment` has the method `getActiveProfiles()` which returns an array of Strings (that is why `[0]` is used in my answer) which we can call using standard Spring EL.

If more than one profiles are active at a time, a more robust solution would be to use Thymeleaf's `#arrays` utility object in order to check for the presence of the string `production` in the active profiles. The code in that case would be:

```
<div th:if="${#arrays.contains(@environment.getActiveProfiles(),'production')}">
     This is the production profile
</div>
```

Comment: @occurred Glad to help! It would help future readers if you accept the answer, because that way that could easily tell if it's correct without having to read the comments

Comment: Meanwhile there is also `acceptsProfiles(String... profiles)` in `Environment`, which makes the check a little smoother: `@environment.acceptsProfiles('production')`

Comment: Note that [`Environment.acceptsProfiles(String ...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#acceptsProfiles(java.lang.String...)) has been deprecated as of v5.1. I've opened [Issue #30206](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30206) asking if they want to reconsider deprecation, pointing them to this discussion here.

Comment: Instead of `acceptsProfiles(String…)`, which has been deprecated, you should now be using `matchesProfiles(String...)`. See [Spring Framework Issue #30206](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30206).

Answer (score 5):

Simply add this class which allows to set global variables for views:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BuildPropertiesController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @ModelAttribute("isProd")
    public boolean isProd() {
        return Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("production");
    }
}
```

And then use `${isProd}` variable in your thymeleaf file:

```
<div th:if="${isProd}">
     This is the production profile
</div>
```

Or you can set active profile name as a global variable:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BuildPropertiesController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @ModelAttribute("profile")
    public String activeProfile() {
        return env.getActiveProfiles()[0];
    }
}
```

And then use `${profile}` variable in your thymeleaf file (if you have one active profile):

```
<div>
     This is the <span th:text="${profile}"></span> profile
</div>
```