# How to show ENV details on UI

Tags: spring, web-services, web

I have one requirement to indicate the user that they are using a development environment or test environment or production environment on UI.
I need suggestion on this which will be more robust and requires less maintenance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html), one for each environment that you have.

For example you can have profiles for: development, qa, uat and production and the only that you need to pass to your application is a property like

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="<<environment_that_you_want>>"
```

Then to show on your views (if you're using spring mvc and tymeleaf) you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23712069/1228193) explanation

Hope it helps.